# The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, scheduler, alarm

I am trying to  develop an app for Windows Phone 8.1 , i need to add a using directive to include the namespace that contains the Reminder class . when i add  "using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;"
but when I try to build the solution, I get this error :

> The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Check the targeted platform at the bottom the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder), it is for WP8.1 Silverlight only, and you are referencing it in a WP8.1 Universal App project.